# Install Windows 8 Apps from a Local Source?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Windows 8 Application from a Local Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407334/install-windows-8-application-from-a-local-source)

How do you install Windows 8 apps you create from a local source? Is that possible? And if it is possible, how would you come across doing something like that?

Or would you have to submit it to the Microsoft Store?

I ask because I need to create an application that is private for a company, but haven't come across any documentation, or anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options for side-loading, but in your particular circumstance "*application that is private for a company*", the best reference is [How to Add and Remove Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx).

In a nutshell for Windows 8 Enterprise devices, if they are joined to a domain, you can sideload the application (from the .appx file).  For other versions of Windows 8 (or non-domain joined), you would need to purchase a [sideloading product activation key](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation.aspx).